# Итерация файлов по маске boost

Tags: c++, linux, boost

Я использую библиотеку boost для работы с файлами. Мне необходимо выбирать файлы из определенной директории по маске. Есть какой-то способ сделать это?

Comment: `directory_iterator` + проверка по маске.

Comment: directory_iterator-ом я пользуюсь и так, а как сделать эту самую проверку?

Comment: Получить из итератора имя файла и проверить очевидно.

Comment: Можете привести пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: На основе `boost.Regex` сделайте предикат, который возвращает `true` если имя файла соответствует регулярному выражению. Сделайте из этого предиката `boost::filter_iterator` и оберните его вокруг `directory_iterator`